# Como fazer com que o google search ache meu site

Tags: google, seo

Estou seguindo os passos para SEO e fazer meu site aparecer nas buscas do google.
As configurações do google search eu já fiz, inclusive o site já é analisado pelo google analytics mas não está sendo encontrado pelo search para que eu possa verificar o site.

```
 Falha na verificação para http://meuendereco.com/ usando o método Google Analytics (7 minutos atrás). A conexão com seu servidor atingiu o tempo limite.
```

[image: CONSOLE]

Fiz todas as tentativas com as alternativas que aparecem do google search porém não tenho êxito.

Comment: O problema não é no *Google Webmasters* ou *Analytics*, ao testar um serviço que acessa outros sites: http://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php com sua URL obtive o seguinte erro: `Connection timed out (110)`, basicamente é o mesmo erro que o webmasters/tools apresentou, no entanto ao acessar seu site diretamente ele abriu normal, então presumo que o problema seja um *Firewall* ou até mesmo com o *DNS*, a única maneira de resolver é se você tiver acesso ao servidor e rede aonde esta o teu site ou você entrar em contato com o suporte da sua "Hospedagem" para que eles façam a liberação.

Comment: Problema resolvido, o meu server estava bloqueando os bots.